# WCF Service Problems

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, wcf

I'm having trouble setting up my WCF Service to an IIS server. The current setup I have is a WCF service written in C# that accesses an external database (located on a different server, different location than our IIS server) and an ASP.NET web site that consumes the service on our server, and uses it's methods to query, then display some data.

Before I uploaded the Service and website to our server, I tested it using the default setup done by Visual Studio. This test led to promising results, because when I let visual studio host the service (and whatever else it does in order to setup the environment for testing) and consume it with the website, everything went smoothly, and all of my queries went through flawlessly.

I can upload the service fine, consume it fine with the website, but I have problems when my service makes queries to the external database. I get an "underlying provider failed on open" error when an actual query is made. I've tried a few different things and I couldn't find an answer. For legal reasons , I'm not allowed to upload the code, but I think this problem is due to incorrect setup on the server.

Comment: What database are you using? Since you mention entity-framework, is it SQL-Server? If so, are you using windows authentication to form your connection string?

Comment: Yes it is a SQL Server. I believe we are using windows authentication, I just know for a fact we're using the Entity Framework, and an id and login to access the database. I'm not sure on much else, the connection string was setup prior to this application being assigned to me. Thanks for the help! I hope this information helps narrow it down

Comment: Turn on WCF logging and examine the logs with the Service Trace Viewer tool. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526(v=vs.110).aspx  Any underlying WCF exceptions should appear in the trace logs.

Comment: My suggestion is to take a look at the app pool in IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're using Entity Framework, that problem almost always indicates that there is an issue establishing a connection to your database. Check your connection string and make sure that the server and instance names are correct, and that the user your service is running under has access to the database. If you're hosting in IIS, this would usually be a service account (e.g. NETWORK SERVICE) or local system account.

Comment: This is what I've been trying to figure out. The thing that strikes me as odd, is that it works when I connect with the default localhost settings, but when I push it to the IIS server I get these errors. Is it possible IIS is not using the credentials from the connection string? I'm not exactly sure what's going on in between IIS and the database access.

Comment: When you connect locally the service is running under your account, whereas when you host it in IIS it's running under a service account. Find out what service account it's running under and give that account permissions on the database.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will double check this to see what our settings are like. Would the network account be related to the app pool ? I've been doing reading on this and I had read somewhere that the app pool determines what account is used.

Answer (score 1):

The issue ended up being the connection string in the end. On my local machine, the name of the server was resolved with the Hosts file, but the server had nowhere to resolve the name of the server mentioned in the connection string. This was causing the issue. This has been resolved by updating the server hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this error on new installations of SQL Server, and I fixed it by enabling Named Pipes in SQL Server Configuration Manager.  Could be the same issue you're having.

Comment: The issue is though that I don't have administrator rights on the server I'm accessing. I have just a simple user account, which has access to read from it. Thanks though, I may need to contact someone about rights on the server.